# Panel on the right: how?

Tags: xfce, openbox

I love the right panel I use in Windows (see the picture).
I tried to mimick the same under Ubuntu interface, also via XFCE and OpenBox. NONE of them support this option natively, everywhere you need to apply a lot of tweaks that work not very stable. This seems to be ridiculously simple, yet very hard to implement.

if you have the "dock" on the right, can you please share your experience? I am stuck.

[image]

Comment: It would not be so difficult to implement, but it is a design decision by Canonical to have a launcher on the left. This can not be overruled by a simple option or setting. If you want a launcher on the right (or anywhere else), try Docky or Plank (both available [here](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/docky)) or Cairo-dock (available [here](http://www.glx-dock.org/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xfce can replicate exactly what your screen shot above does. Here is my screen shot of something very similar I have created on my desktop. (Please overlook minor aesthetics like color etc.)

[image: Xfce side panel]

1. Open Panel Preferences and set Mode to Deskbar.
2. Go ahead and add your program launchers. These can be dragged from your menu. You will also want to add the other items you want with the plus button under the Items tab.
3. To have a gap between the top and bottom, insert a separator between your Window Buttons item and the Launchers. Set the Separator to transparent and check expand.
4. Next go to Display > Measurements. You will need to play around with Row Size, Number of rows, and Length, but after fiddling with it you should be able to get just what you want.

Please note that in regard to icon size, you can use whatever image you want for your icons.

Xfce is really customizable, so you should be able to get just what you like.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the language switcher, the audio settings and other things in a small icons.

Comment: To clarify about the icon size, I think the clickable area would still be the same, so you might as well use the normal size icon. The way to make those icons that you mention smaller would be to decrease Row Size and increase the Number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this could be done for Unity, for for the XFCE panel, you can right click the panel, go to "Panel Preferences" and make sure the "Lock Panel" is unchecked. Then you will get a couple of handles on the top and left with which you can drag the panel to the place of your liking. You can then go back and recheck the "Lock Panel" switch to lock it in place.

Openbox does not come with a default panel, so you may be using a different panel without knowing, so look at the preferences and documentation for that particular panel for more information on how to move it to the right side of the screen.

Comment: in xfce I wasn't able to correctly resize the icons, so that the systems icons was small, but the open windows were flat...

Comment: What do you mean by "The open windows were flat"? It'd also be great if you could possible edit your answer with a screenshot of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `.deb` called "Docky" on the Ubuntu Software Center that you can put on any edge of the screen. I've never had any problems with it and it looks much better than the default launcher.

Comment: does docky allow non icons? I need "flat icons" ther perfectly display the names...

Comment: Docky does not allow non icons :/ sorry, hope you find one that works. I'll keep looking for one and let you know in a separate answer if I find it.